# How to rename an Amazon RDS hosted PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have restored a snapshot from an existing RDS PostgreSQL database. Now I want to rename that database but can't find how to do it anywhere in the AWS documentation.

Nor can I find how to use the master password (which I expect let's me do it).

Comment: `alter database rename`?

Comment: current user doesn't have permissions: ERROR: permission denied to rename database

Comment: Try switching your user to the Postgres user (eg. postgres) and then run the rename command

Comment: User postgres is not owner, getting `ERROR: must be owner of database <db>`. Trying to set postgres as OWNER gives me `ERROR: must be member of role "postgres"`. Shouldn't be that hard to rename a db ..

Comment: @kev This is a very late reply, but you need to use the "master" user, which might not be `postgres`. You can whatever user that is in the RDS details for an instance.

Answer (score 5):

Logging in with *postgres* into *template1* database and then `ALTER DATABASE foo RENAME TO bar;` worked

Comment: You can login to the `postgres` database too (if your instance/cluster has one) – probably any database *other* than the one you want to rename.